# How to copy an aws private bucket to azure storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azcopy

I want to copy a folder with large files in it to azure storage.

I found this article that shows how to copy a public aws bucket to azure: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip220.html

But how can I do this, if the aws bucket is private? How can I pass the credentials to azcopy for it to copy my files from aws bucket to azure directly?

Comment: is your Blob/File Storage container  publicly accessible?

Comment: @AsriBadlah No both of the storages are private. I know how to setup azure azcopy to use my credential, but there is no way that I can provide information about aws account credential to azcopy.

Comment: The problem is not how to pass AWS or Azure credentials to azcopy, the root cause is there is no network connectivity between AWS account and Azure account, which you can do using multi cloud connections provider (Aviatrix) check the following example: https://docs.aviatrix.com/HowTos/GettingStartedAzureToAWSAndGCP.html

Comment: @AsriBadlah If you look at this document: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip220.html you would see that azcopy has a command option to copy a bucket from aws to azure, but the above document assumes that both storages are public. My question is how I can use this method when both storages are private?

Comment: Yeah I am aware about azcopy tool, they mentioned that both storage should be public to use internet for connectivity, since both of them are private you can not use internet so have to create another connecctivity between AWS and Azure which Aviatrix provide

Comment: The 'publicly accessible' statement in that Azure azcopy article seems very misleading. The tool supports both Azure and AWS credentials. I don't think it requires the objects to be publicly readable at all. It wouldn't be very useful if it did.

Comment: [Copy data from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage by using AzCopy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3) does not mention the need for publicly-accessible data either.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the article has a section which states how to set the aws access key and id, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3#authorize-with-aws-s3, As it is your reference to the article, please raise it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Copy data from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage by using AzCopy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3):

> AzCopy is a command-line utility that you can use to copy blobs or files to or from a storage account. This article helps you copy objects, directories, and buckets from Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 to Azure blob storage by using AzCopy.

The article explains how to provide both Azure and AWS credentials.

One thing to note is that Amazon S3 cannot 'send' data to Azure Blob Storage. Therefore, something will need to call `GetObject()` on S3 to retrieve the data, and then send it to Azure. I'm assuming that Azure Blob Storage cannot directly request data from Amazon S3, so it means that the data will be 'downloaded' from S3, then 'uploaded' to Azure. To improve efficiency, run the AzCopy command either from an AWS or an Azure virtual machine, to reduce the latency of sending via your own computer.

Comment: This is not fully correct. I ran the application from my laptop and azure get the data from aws at the rate of 5GB/s much much faster than my network. When you give the credential to azcopy, it sends the credentials to the azure centre and then the azure cloud download data from aws very fast. So if you run the command from any system it is very fast.

Comment: Ah! So it seems my assumption is wrong. Azure must provide a special feature that can pull directly from S3. It might be this: [Move your data from AWS S3 to Azure Storage using AzCopy | Azure blog and updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/move-your-data-from-aws-s3-to-azure-storage-using-azcopy/)

Comment: please update answer with above information

Answer (score 0):

One solution, albeit not an ideal one is that you could request an [AWS Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/faqs/) with your bucket data on it, then use [Azure Import/Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service) service to send the Snowball to Azure for ingestion.

Comment: Do you know if they use compatible formats? I couldn't find any information about Azure <--> Snowball integration online.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating a pre-signed url with limited ttl on it for the duration of the copy?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

that way you can just execute azcopy <aws_presigned_url> <azure_sas_url>

the url contains the information you need for authn/authz on both sides.